# A distance function on a Riemannian manifold which can be viewed as a distance function to the point at infinity.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complete-spaces

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y).$ Find a sequence $(p_i)_{i\in \mathbb {N}}$ of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that $f(.)=\operatorname{lim}_{i\to \infty} (d(.,p_i) - d(0,p_i)).$

Here $d$ is the distance function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the standard metric and convergence equals convergence on compact sets .

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ Here $f$ is indeed a distance function because $||\nabla{f}||=1$ identically on $\mathbb{R}^2.$ But I can't exactly approach to find a sequence to satisfy this property . I was thinking to define $g: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(a)=d(a,p_i)$ and then the right hand side of the question looks like $\operatorname{lim}_{i\to \infty} \operatorname{\int}_0^l D(g\circ \gamma)(r) dr $ on a compact set where $\gamma:[0,l]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth curve with $\gamma(0)=0$ and $\gamma(l)=a.$ But I still don't know how to find the sequence $(p_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}.$ Thanks in advance for any help .

Comment: The tags you have chosen, and your attempted methods, seem all entirely irrelevant to this problem. This looks to me like an elementary Euclidean geometry question with limits added in for fun.

Comment: Thanks, can you please give some hints ? I tried it avoiding the riemannian geometry ways but then couldn't find the sequence.

Comment: I'm curious where this question comes from. It *looks* like a computation of a [Busemann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busemann_function), which gave me a hint to the answer.

Comment: The level sets of the distance function from a point are circles. If you fix a point and a line through it, you can look at all circles passing through that point and tangent to the line. If you let the radii $\rightarrow\infty$, the circles converge to the line. So you just choose the sequence of points be the centers of such a sequence of circles. In hyperbolic space , this is indeed exactly how you define Busemann functions.

Comment: @LeeMosher, the problem was to show that this is an example of a distance function but not a $\textit{Riemannian}$ distance function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_i = (-i,-i)$. For any $a=(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, if you plot the triangle with vertices $0,a,p_i$ for large $i$ you will see that the line segment $\overline{0 p_i}$ has slope $+1$ and that the line segment $\overline{a p_i}$ has slope closer and closer to $1$ as $i \to \infty$. From this one can intuit that the limit of $d(a,p_i) - d(0,p_i)$ equals the desired quantity, which (if $x+y>0$) is equal to the length of the slope $+1$ line segment that connects the point $a$ to the slope $-1$ line given by the equation $x+y=0$, i.e. the line $f(x,y)=0$.

To *prove* that it holds,
\begin{align*}
d(a,p_i) &= \sqrt{(x+i)^2 + (y+i)^2} \\
         &= \sqrt{x^2+y^2 + 2(x+y)i + 2i^2} \\
d(0,p_i) &= \sqrt{2} \, i \\
d(a,p_i) - d(0,p_i) &= \sqrt{x^2+y^2 + 2(x+y)i + 2i^2} - \sqrt{2} \, i \\
  &= \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2 + 2(x+y)i + 2i^2} - \sqrt{2} \, i }{1}
\end{align*}
and now you can finish computing the limit by first rationalizing the numerator, and then multiplying the resulting numerator and denominator $\frac{1}{i}$.

Once one has that limit calculation in hand, one can easily use it to observe that the convergence is uniform as $a=(x,y)$ varies over any compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Note that one can guess "where the point at infinity is" by looking at the direction of $\nabla f$. Here, it is $(1,1)$, which tells us that we are looking at the distance from something that is in the direction of $\Bbb R(-1,1)$.

Comment: Right, although for me it was visualizing the family of slope $-1$ lines in $\mathbb R^2$, i.e. lines of constant $f(x,y)$ value.

Comment: Although both procedures are in fact equivalent, yours appears smarter to me, since you are directly identifying the level hypersurfaces

Comment: The point is that Busemann functions on the hyperbolic plane and linear functions on the Euclidean plane are limits of (shifted) distance functions, because equally spaced lines and horocycles are limits of equally spaced concentric circles.